# c# how to connect and disconnect mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, database-connection

[this is the image of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfrQ2.jpg)  
[image]

What I want is when I click connect button, the connection to MySQL is opened and I can use the connected database and all textboxes become disabled, if I click disconnect, I want to close the connection and user will not be able to use the connected database, and all the textboxes became enabled.

Can anyone help me with this validation !!

This the code which I have in the connect button:

connection is MySQLConnection global variable

```
  connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);

                if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
```

and this the code which I have in disconnect button :

```
 if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

This does not work because when the disconnect button is selected the connection variable becomes null, which I do not want. I want to maintain the state of the connection variable.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.   Post the code you have and where you're stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can store your connection variable in session state, I think the page is post back before you call close connection button. so variable became null
ex:
on Open Connection:

```
connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);

if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   connection.Open();
}
Session["connection"] = connection
```

on Close Connection:

```
connection = (MySqlConnection)Session["connection"];
if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   connection.Close();
}
```

Or you can change connection variable modifier to be static